# EndOfStreamException caused by spammer

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, webforms, viewstate

I have a contact page on my site that seems to have been latched on to by a spammer.

The error itself is:

```
    System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeIndexedString(SerializerBinaryReader reader, Byte token)
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader reader)
```

Google turns up little.

I assume they are submitting an invalid viewstate, but the exception has no line number so im stumped.

Edit: My question is, where can I catch this exception or check the validity of the viewstate.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At webconfig use this (change your target framework . this will make you secure.)

```
<pages validateRequest="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" 
   enableViewStateMac="true" enableSessionState="true"
   controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
</pages>
```

Comment: Which attribute in that string is it which makes the difference? And what are the impacts of changing it?

Comment: @NickG validateRequest="true" 
   enableViewStateMac="true" enableSessionState="true"  validaterequest prevents malicious url request and form submissions

Comment: Does that actually stop the exceptions occurring, or just improve security? I'm unsure what the effect of that configuration is.